# Why does this double JOIN work but this similar one not work?

Tags: sql, join

This is for a Rails app, but I'm just posting the SQL.

So, this is my sanity test. It works, and returns two copies of the same model. And if I don't include the `where` multiple copies of multiple models are returned.

```
SELECT \"outlets\".* 
FROM \"outlets\" 
INNER JOIN \"comments\" 
ON \"comments\".\"commentable_id\" = \"outlets\".\"id\" 
AND \"comments\".\"commentable_type\" = 'Outlet'
INNER JOIN \"statistics\" 
ON \"statistics\".\"statable_id\" = \"outlets\".\"id\" 
AND \"statistics\".\"statable_type\" = 'Outlet' 
WHERE (\"outlets\".\"id\" = '1')

#=> [#<Outlet id: 1...>, #<Outlet id: 1...>]
# without the where I get back something like
# [...id: 1, id: 1, id: 5, id: 5, id: 5, id: 5 ]
```

I'm not sure how to write it so it only returns one value (without just using `distinct`). But that can be my next problem.

This is the SQL I'm trying to make work. I've also tried explicitly specifying `INNER` and reversing the order of the equalities:

```
SELECT \"followings\".* 
FROM \"followings\"
JOIN \"outlets\"
ON \"followings\".\"followable_id\" = \"outlets\".\"id\"
AND \"followings\".\"followable_type\" = 'Outlet'
JOIN \"people\"
ON \"followings\".\"followable_id\" = \"people\".\"id\"
AND \"followings\".\"followable_type\" = 'Person'
WHERE (\"followings\".\"user_id\" = '1')

#=> []
# Exact same result from removing the WHERE clause
```

There are records for each join. If I join on either table individually they both return the results I specially created to test my SQL. So:

```
SELECT \"followings\".* 
FROM \"followings\" 
INNER JOIN \"people\"
ON \"followings\".\"followable_id\" = \"people\".\"id\"
AND \"followings\".\"followable_type\" = 'Person' 
WHERE (\"followings\".\"user_id\" = '1')

#=> [<Following id: 2...>]
# And id: 1 for joining on outlets without people
```

The part that stumps me here is that the working version and the not-working version are essentially the same, but I don't see why it should work one place and not the other

EDIT:

Progress, changing the `JOIN`'s for `followings` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s will return the desired results. But then why is it working where `outlets.id` `= commentable_id` and `= statable_id` at the same time?

And, I just tried changing the `outlets` to LOJ's as well, and that returned a list of results that is approximately double the length of the outlets table itself in about the longest SQL call I've ever seen. So, while it's progress I don't think it's a general solution.

EDIT 2:

Thanks to testing things out with the accepted answer I realized that my choice of statistics was giving "misleading" results because each outlet has a statistic. When I changed to a better test table (e.g. `followings`) both `JOIN`'s behaved similarly. And the `UNION` method returns the expected entries

Comment: The `followings.followable_type` can't be both `= 'Outlet'` and `= 'Person'` at the same time for the 2nd query. Did you mean to use `outlets` and `people` for those comparisons?

Comment: I thought of that but in my working example `outlets.id` `= commentable_id` and `= statable_id` at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you want, I think. You can get the two lists separately and then combine them with `UNION`.

```
SELECT followings.*
FROM followings
JOIN outlets ON followings.followable_id = outlets.id
WHERE followable_type = 'Outlet'

UNION

SELECT followings.*
FROM followings
JOIN people ON followings.followable_id = people.id
WHERE followable_type = 'Person'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem query, change it like below. Make the  `\"followings\".\"followable_type\"` a `OR` condition (Have used `IN` operator). I have as well, removed the condition from JOIN to WHERE clause.

```
SELECT \"followings\".* 
FROM \"followings\"
JOIN \"outlets\"
ON \"followings\".\"followable_id\" = \"outlets\".\"id\"
JOIN \"people\"
ON \"followings\".\"followable_id\" = \"people\".\"id\"
WHERE (\"followings\".\"user_id\" = '1')
AND \"followings\".\"followable_type\" IN ('Outlet','Person')
```

You can as well say

```
WHERE (\"followings\".\"user_id\" = '1')
AND (
\"followings\".\"followable_type\" = 'Outlet'
 OR 
\"followings\".\"followable_type\" = 'Person'
  )
```

**EDIT:**

Add the condition to JOIN itself, No need of a WHERE then

```
SELECT \"followings\".* 
FROM \"followings\"
JOIN \"outlets\"
ON \"followings\".\"followable_id\" = \"outlets\".\"id\"
AND \"followings\".\"followable_type\" IN ('Outlet','Person')
AND (\"followings\".\"user_id\" = '1')
JOIN \"people\"
ON \"followings\".\"followable_id\" = \"people\".\"id\"
```

Comment: So, this does return one entry, but not the other. Which I'm surprised to see. Also, I would vastly prefer if this were to be done using `JOIN`s.

Comment: it only returned `Following id: 1` which is `join`ed to `people`. For some reason they both ignored the second one `join`ed to `outlets`. That's the same for both the original and the edit.

Comment: @MCB, it should be right? based on your condition `WHERE (\"followings\".\"user_id\" = '1')`

Comment: @MCB, Per your post it's correct to me; to go one step further I need to take a look at sample data but then that's altogether a separate question. You may want to post a separate thread with sample data and table DDL.

Comment: I'm sorry @Rahul but your SQL didn't work. It only returns one entry when it should return both, and none of it answers my real question about why the given `JOIN`s are behaving differently. If the SQL did work I probably would accept it if no one else gave the more complete answer to my question, but unfortunately it does neither.